# Alterar variavel definida e receber novo valor via formulario

Tags: php, html

Tenho uma varivel ***$CONFIG['SiteTitle'] = 'Titulo do meu site';***

Essa variavel esta no arquivo *config.php* e incluso na header para definir o titulo de todas as paginas. Recentemente crie uma nova página para o site as configurações gerais. Nessa página quero colocar um formulario aonde posso alterar o valor dessa variavel ***$CONFIG['SiteTitle']***.

```
<form>
   <label>Titulo do site:</label>
   <input type="text" value="<?php echo $CONFIG['SiteTitle']; >">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

No form manda o texto da nova página para o php por post:

```
<form method="post" action="caminho/config.php">
    <input type="text" name="titulo">
</form>
```

Na página config.php verifica se existe o post e se ele não está vazio, então atribui o seu valor a variável:

```
if(isset($_POST["titulo"]) && $_POST["titulo"] != "")
    $CONFIG["SiteTitle"] = $_POST["titulo"];
```

Comment: poderia ser sem o action="caminho/config.php" ? o config.php e um arquivo de apoio aonde defino api de plugins url base do site gostaria de fazer esse processo na configuration.php.

Comment: Claro, so dei um exemplo pode fazer em qualquer arquivo (desde que seja .php) inclusive no próprio arquivo que esta o form (porém isso pode deichar o código meio bagunçado, MVC no mesmo arquivo)